# Using dynamic roles in security.yml

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have a Ldap repository storing roles for users. They are already mapped to Symfony roles.
I would like to use them in the security.yml but I cannot hard code role values because they evolve with the application.
Is it possible to have something like this?

access_control:

```
    - { path: ^/project/$project, roles: ROLE_$project_MEMBER }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way and it's not good to do it the way I wanted, I've ended using the [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) system using affirmative strategy

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at implementing [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)? See also [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html) piece of documentation.

Comment: Yes i've read that, but it's not a solution for me.
I have routes like this :
localhost/project/{projectName}/show
for each project, the members can have some roles like : ROLE_PROJECT_ADMIN, ... and I would like to do the check using security.yml as described above

Answer (score 0):

i'm also stuck in the same problem you have to give roles which is stored in your in DB  like

access_control:

```
    - { path: ^/Services/, role: ROLE_USER }
```